# Generate a map for a roguelike

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, path-finding, maze

## Today, we'll be generating a map for a roguelike RPG!

### Example Map:

```
##########
####    F#
####    ##
##    C#C#
#     ## #
# C   #E #
####  #  #
#        #
#P       #
##########
```

`#` are walls, `P` is the player's starting location, `F` is the finish that must be reached, `C` are coins that can be collected, and `E` are enemies that can be fought.

### Map specifications:

- Height and Width should both be between 10 and 39, inclusive. Height does not have to equal width.
- The maps borders should be filled in with walls.
- `P` should be placed in the bottom left corner.
- `F` should be placed in the top right corner.
- There should be between 1 and 3 enemies.
- There should be between 2 and 4 coins.
- There should be some amount of walls in the middle. There should be a path to get from `P` to Every `C`, `E`, and `F`, keeping in mind that the player cannot move diagonally.
- Every possible combination should have some chance of occurring.

### Rules

- Fewest byte program wins.
- Your program should not take any input.
- Your program may not exit with an error (non-fatal output is `STDERR` is ok, but we can't have our rogue-like crash after map generation!)
- A single trailing newline is allowed and trailing space is allowed.
- No other output is allowed.

Comment: It's roguelike, just fyi.

Comment: Can you clarify "every possible combination should have an equal chance of occurring"? Do you literally mean that all the valid maps (in particular, all maps where P can reach all the C/E/Fs) must occur with equal probability? If so, it seems that the only possible algorithm is to generate maps uniformly at random and then check that P can reach everything, discarding invalid maps until that happens.

Comment: Can you also clarify - "There should be some amount of walls in the middle", what if I place only 2 walls all the time?

Comment: @GregMartin I'll change it too "Every possible layout should have a chance of occurring", not necessarily an equal chance.

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur Then there will be valid layouts that your algorithm has no chance of generating.

Comment: I think "some chance of occurring" is an improvement! Given that, I think you can delete "(You may assume your language's built in random number generator is uniformly random)"

Comment: `#######~#PCCEF#~#######` is the smallest possible?

Comment: @carusocomputing It has to be at least 10 by 10.

Comment: The tricky part is paving a way from P to F ... I guess that should be random too? (That´s what `every possible layout` implies for me.)

Comment: @Titus Every possible layout means every possible configuration of `#`, `P`, `F`, `C`, and `E` that fits the spec. So yes, the path can't be constant.

Comment: What about unreachable empty squares surrounded by walls? Is it a valid layout or should they be avoided altogether? (In other words: should each empty square be reachable?)

Comment: @Arnauld no, empty squares can be unreachable and count as separate layouts.

Comment: And can the player pass through coins and enemies? (by collecting / killing them)

Comment: @arnauld yes, he can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Perl, 293 bytes

*-9 bytes thanks to @Dom Hastings*

```pl
{$==7+rand 30;@r=$"=();@a=((C)x4,(E)x3,("#")x1369,(" ")x1369);for$i(0..7+rand 30){$r[$i][$_]=splice@a,rand@a,1for 0..$=}$r[0][$=]=F;$r[-1][0]=P;$_=$r=join$/,$v="#"x($=+=3),(map"#@$_#",@r),$v;1while$r=~s/F(.{$=})?[^#F]/F$1F/s||$r=~s/[^#F](.{$=})?F/F$1F/s;$r!~/[CEP]/&&/C.*C/s&&/E/?last:redo}say
```

Add `-E` flag to run it:

```
perl -E '{$==7+rand 30;@r=$"=();@a=((C)x4,(E)x3,("#")x1369,(" ")x1369);for$i(0..7+rand 30){$r[$i][$_]=splice@a,rand@a,1for 0..$=}$r[0][$=]=F;$r[-1][0]=P;$_=$r=join$/,$v="#"x($=+=3),(map"#@$_#",@r),$v;1while$r=~s/F(.{$=})?[^#F]/F$1F/s||$r=~s/[^#F](.{$=})?F/F$1F/s;$r!~/[CEP]/&&/C.*C/s&&/E/?last:redo}say'
```

However, it takes a long time to run, so I recommend using this version instead:

```
perl -E '{${$_}=8+rand 30for"=","%";@r=$"=();@a=((C)x4,(E)x3,("#")x($v=rand $=*$%),(" ")x($=*$%-$v));for$i(0..$%-1){$r[$i][$_]=splice@a,rand@a,1for 0..$=-1}$r[0][$=-1]=F;$r[$%-1][0]=P;$_=$r=join$/,$v="#"x($=+=2),(map"#@$_#",@r),$v;1while$r=~s/F(.{$=})?[^#F]/F$1F/s||$r=~s/[^#F](.{$=})?F/F$1F/s;$r!~/[CEP]/&&/C.*C/s&&/E/?last:redo}say'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BT4NAEIX/Ci7TdrelLFgPxs2kJATOvRMkq8UUg4Xsmoqh9K/jgHra2e@9N/NetD2NY1ua2tkmzqqHHooBHzdGn4/OLnhrDEPmsQVTkUFgyIWKNHIei@7B44nodh5nLhMdhwvOIcA1LARRZ6bTbwsXIRTtgooHvk8gFD2YDKo8gyJH29bVaxlpb1pAT0hWZzLiNhzIF5CNxhxTNaUonhPDg4ICweB7U51BelSAmkwnN3hPBT50y9wICpd5kREkq/DrVNUlJW5WptzvAQexz57dNJcphKm01@uvOLN/Q/on0u27m8zi5JDL5VLG/jqWloZE7mttP59MeWwGq79X4/gD)

**Explanation**

```pl
{                     # enter a block (which is used as a loop)
    {$==7+rand 30;                   # randomly select the width of the map -2
                                     # (-2 because we don't include the borders yet)
    @r=$"=();                        # reset @r, and set $" to undef
    @a=(                             # create a list of the character that can be on the board
     (C)x4,                          #  4 coins 'C'
     (E)x3,                          #  3 enemies 'E'
     ("#")x1369,                     #  37*37 '#'
     (" ")x1369);                    #  37*37 spaces
    for$i(0..7+rand 30)                # create the 2D map (7+rand 30 is the height, which is generated just now)
      for$_(0..$=-1){
        $r[$i][$_]=                    # index [$i][$_] receives ...
           splice@a,rand@a,1           # .. a random character from the list previously generated
                                       # (the character is then removed from the list thanks to 'splice')
      }
    }
    $r[0][$=]=F;                       # add the finish cell
    $r[-1][0]=P;                       # add the start cell
    $_=$r=                             # here we generate a string representation of the map
          join$/,                      # join the following elements with newlines
            $v="#"x($=+=3),            # a first line of # only
            (map"#@$_#",@r),           # add a # to the beginning and the end of each line
            $v;                        # the last line of #

    1while                # the following regex will replace every accessible cell with a F
       $r=~s/F(.{$=})?[^#F]/F$1F/s  # a cell on the right or the bottom of a F cell is replaced  
         ||                         # or
       $r=~s/[^#F](.{$=})?F/F$1F/s; # a cell on the left or the top of a F cell is replaced
    $r!~/[CEP]/         # if there is no C, E or P on the map (meaning they were all accessible)
     && /C.*C/s         #  and there are at least 2 coins
     && /E/ ?           #  and 1 enemy
      last:             # the the map is valid, we exit the loop
      redo              # else, start over
}
say                     # and print the board
```

It takes a long time to run, because the list from which we randomly pick the characters to put on the board (`@a`) contains 1369 whitespaces and `#`, and only 4 coins and 3 enemies. So if the size of the width and height are small, there are a lot of spaces and `#` compared to the coin and the enemies, so it's quite likely that a random map won't be valid. That's why the "optimized" version is faster: the list from which we pick the characters is just a little bigger than the map (the list is `@a=((C)x4,(E)x3,("#")x($v=rand $=*$%),($")x($=*$%-$v))` : a random number `$v` of `#` (inferior to the size of the map), and `size of the map - $v` whitespaces).

Comment: I don't really know perl, but looking at the syntax highlighting you appear to have an unmatched quote in ($")x$=**2);. Out maybe the highlighting doesn't work right and that's a feature. Also, whitespace can be unreachable.

Comment: @Pavel `$"` is a legit Perl variable, but the syntax highlighting doesn't know about it, that's why it looks like that. Ok, I'll delete the comment about unreachable spaces.

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, <s>422</s> <s>417</s> <s>415</s> <s>309</s> <s>373</s> <s>369</s> <s>364</s> 361 bytes

```php
function w($p){global$r,$h,$w;for($q=$p;$r[$q]<A;)for($r[$p=$q]=" ";($q=$p+(1-(2&$m=rand()))*($m&1?:$w))%$w%($w-1)<1|$q/$w%$h<1;);}$r=str_pad("",($w=rand(10,39))*$h=rand(10,39),"#");$r[$w*2-2]=F;w($p=$q=$w*(--$h-1)+1);$r[$p]=P;for($c=rand(2,4);$i<$c+rand(1,3);$p=rand($w,$h*$w))if($r[$p]<A&&$p%$w%($w-1)){w($p);$r[$p]=EC[$i++<$c];w($p);}echo chunk_split($r,$w);
```

operates on a string without linebreaks; digs random paths between the extras.  Run with `-r`.

**Note:** The paths are created by walking in random directions. The choice of direction for every step will mostly generate maps that are wide open; and the example map is very unlikely to appear; but it *is* possible.

**breakdown**

```php
// aux function: randomly walk away from $p placing spaces, stop when a special is reached
function w($p)
{global$r,$h,$w;
    for($q=$p;
        $r[$q]<A;                               // while $q is not special
    )
        for($r[$p=$q]=" ";                          // 3. replace with space
            ($q=$p+(1-(2&$m=rand()))*($m&1?:$w))    // 1. pick random $q next to $p
            %$w%($w-1)<1|$q/$w%$h<1;                // 2. that is not on the borders
        );
}

// initialize map
$r=str_pad("",
    ($w=rand(10,39))*$h=rand(10,39) // random width and height
    ,"#");                          // fill with "#"
$r[$w*2-2]=F;                       // place Finish
w($p=$q=$w*(--$h-1)+1);             // build path from Player position to F
// $h is now height -1 !
$r[$p]=P;                           // place Player

// place Coins ans Enemies
for($c=rand(2,4);$i<$c+rand(1,3);   // while $i has not reached no. of coins+no. of enemies
    $p=rand($w,$h*$w))              // pick a random position
    if($r[$p]<A&&$p%$w%($w-1))      // that is neither special nor out of bounds
    {
        w($p);                      // build path from there to another special
        $r[$p]=EC[$i++<$c];         // place this special
        w($p);      // additional path to allow special in the middle of a dead end tunnel
    }

// insert linebreaks and print
echo chunk_split($r,$w);
```

Comment: In your explanation you're generating height and width to 37, not to 39.

Comment: @Pavel fixed; thanks for noticing

Comment: Outputs it's own source code when I tried in on [Try it online](http://www.tio.run/nexus)

Comment: @Pavel you need to surround the code with `<?php .... ?>`

Comment: Ok, I did that, and I noticed that the walls are generated in regular rectangular chunks. It should be able to generate something like the example map. It also doesn't always generate `E`s.

Comment: •Every possible combination should have some chance of occurring, there should be 1 to 3 Es, and 2 to 4 Cs. You might want to read the spec.

Comment: @Pavel no need for `<?php` tags (and no need for a file) if you use `php -nr 'code'`

Comment: @Pavel now complete and everything fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 730 bytes

```cs
var R=new Random();for(;;){char P='P',C='C',E='E',Q='#';int w=R.Next(8,37),h=R.Next(8,37),H=h,t,g=99,W,i,j,r;string l,s,p=new string(Q,w+2);var m=new List<string>();for(;H>0;H--){l="";for(W=w;W>0;W--){r=R.Next(999);l+=r<3?C:r<6?E:r<g?Q:' ';}m.Add(l);}m[0]=m[0].Substring(0,w-1)+'F';m[h-1]=P+m[h-1].Substring(1);s=String.Join("#\n#",m);t=s.Split(E).Length-1;if(t<1||t>3)continue;t=s.Split(C).Length-1;if(t<2||t>4)continue;while(g>0){g--;for(i=0;i<h;i++)for(j=0;j<w;j++)if(m[i][j]!=Q&&m[i][j]!=P&&(i>0&&m[i-1][j]==P)||(i<h-1&&m[i+1][j]==P)||(j>0&&m[i][j-1]==P)||(j<w-1&&m[i][j+1]==P))m[i]=m[i].Substring(0,j)+P+m[i].Substring(j+1,w-j-1);}if(String.Join("",m).Split(E,C,'F').Length>1)continue;Console.Write(p+"\n#"+s+"#\n"+p);break;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHBjtowEIZfhQYJ27ITJUvVNutMUBVRoWpVBTjkQDmwkE2cJg5KvE0l2GendoAu9DKa@fx7PP5n29rbVpxOvzfNYAEy7QaLjdzVFSb8pW4w5@SwzfVZDChGLAIUITYFNEVsDmiIuJBq0MHC@ZH@UfgLG38mLL8vZ5AzxTLwfZYwwQrW8FY1QmaDkrVs3795BnjOOvpAuJml6vmTaFVwPgyvE81Cl89smxxKsKweJdDxRNPE0Ob6uu/7hJcUmmA8iR6b4NNkqmM2mT@iAeJvlfN1t8Ml0dnKXYMJzvL1@TKJyzrbIxR9Q7xa5ba3hpiekxuRR3gLyz53vtdCYmv4Uw4tVhGuoHWW@1IoPCXOUyozpe9y8YJV4B2PKhyTbS2VkK/pjTT6X/pgpB/fpV0uyhRnoUsOmW33fxfgchHkXFBKTF3ougg6Xuha96hWYr0q1h9gPhr9y@PRCIvQ7Yn@kWYAMTkesW5kez2mt7i4aDUyTlxg0F20GtMzJqYCE@6sLAg17t1RfUVbrPvpBeg571w0Dl7dYxHTS7gaE3rvZkS1bOsydZJGqBTvqWW8py01S7DonvDnJt384m@n018)

Ungolfed:

```cs
var R = new Random();
for (;;)
{
    char P = 'P', C = 'C', E = 'E', poundSymbol = '#';
    int width = R.Next(8, 37), height = R.Next(8, 37), HeightTemp = height, testVariable, goThroughLoop = 99, WidthTemp, i, j, rand;
    string line, strMap, poundSymbolPadding = new string(poundSymbol, width + 2);

    var map = new List<string>(); //initialize map
    for (; HeightTemp > 0; HeightTemp--)
    {
        line = "";
        for (WidthTemp = width; WidthTemp > 0; WidthTemp--)
        {
            rand = R.Next(999);
            //add a character randomly.  Re-use the goThroughLoop variable here, which gives approx. 1 wall per 10 spaces.
            line += rand < 3 ? C : rand < 6 ? E : rand < goThroughLoop ? poundSymbol : ' ';
        }
        map.Add(line);
    }
    //add finish and player
    map[0] = map[0].Substring(0, width - 1) + 'F';
    map[height - 1] = P + map[height - 1].Substring(1);

    strMap = String.Join("#\n#", map);
    //check proper # of enemies, regenerate if invalid
    testVariable = strMap.Split(E).Length - 1;
    if (testVariable < 1 || testVariable > 3)
        continue;
    //check proper # of coins, regenerate if invalid
    testVariable = strMap.Split(C).Length - 1;
    if (testVariable < 2 || testVariable > 4)
        continue;
    //map out areas Player can access.  Iterates until all accessible places have been marked as such.
    while (goThroughLoop > 0)
    {
        goThroughLoop--;
        for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
                if (map[i][j] != poundSymbol && map[i][j] != P && ((i > 0 && map[i - 1][j] == P) || (i < height - 1 && map[i + 1][j] == P) || (j > 0 && map[i][j - 1] == P) || (j < width - 1 && map[i][j + 1] == P)))
                    //mark this space as accessible
                    map[i] = map[i].Substring(0, j) + P + map[i].Substring(j + 1, width - j - 1);
    }
    //if player cannot access all features (defeated enmies, collected coins, arrived at finish), regenerate map.
    if (String.Join("", map).Split(E, C, 'F').Length > 1)
        continue;

    //output our final map
    Console.Write(poundSymbolPadding + "\n#" + strMap + "#\n" + poundSymbolPadding);

    break;
}
```

Edit: saved 8 bytes, made it slightly less efficient by locking the player accessible test loop to 99 iterations.  I know it'll never really compete with the other answers here, but I'm having fun!

Comment: @GregMartin Now it's your turn to implement it in F#  ;-)

Comment: A simple modulation to the subdominant, no problem :)